# How to query OrderedRealmResult by sorting with to-many relationship?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a to-many relationship in Realm, one object is ChatMessage and another is Contact.

Contact contains ChatMessage as List.

I want to show Contacts by sorting it with the latest ChatMessage, chatMessage contains timestamp value.

I tried with this

`contactData = realm.where(ContactData.class).notEqualTo("contactType", ContactData.TYPE_PROFILE).sort("chatMessages.timestamp").findAll();`

but realm throws error as chatMessage is a list.

So I am looking for the solution to this problem and also I am using realm-recycler-view which binds realm data with recycler view also needs to move the contact on top whenever a new message arrives.

**EDIT**

I am using realm library as 

`classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.7.0"`

and realm adapter 

`implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0'`

Thanks

Comment: This *should* be supported since 3.0.0?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am using 
```
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0'
```

and this 
```
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.7.0"
```

Comment: is `ChatMessages` a `RealmList<`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, ChatMessage itself extends RealmObject, where as in ContactData object which is also RealmObject, ChatMessage is saved as private RealmList<ChatMessage> chatMessages;